# CISmoothLinearGradient Filter crashing

Tags: cifilter

I try to implement some CI filters to my CIImage and one of them keep crash. CISmoothLinearGradient gives below error but I could not understand what is wrong with it. What I try to do is to get certain regions in the image and create smooth linear gradient between based on their average colors.

Error code:
**reason: '[<CISmoothLinearGradient 0x281151960> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key inputImage**

Is there a syntax error?  Please see my code below:

```
                let ROIV1 = CGRect(x: 0, y: 55, width: (histogramImage?.size.width)!, height: 5)
                
                let ROIV2 = CGRect(x: 0, y: 60, width: (histogramImage?.size.width)!, height: 5)

                let newPic1 = maskCI!.cropped(to: ROIV1)
                
                let newPic1UI = maskEdit.convert(cmage: newPic1)
                
                let newPic2 = maskCI!.cropped(to: ROIV2)
                
                let newPic2UI = maskEdit.convert(cmage: newPic2)
                
                let average1 = newPic1UI.averageColor
                
                let average2 = newPic2UI.averageColor

                maskCI = maskCI?.applyingFilter("CISmoothLinearGradient", parameters: ["inputPoint0" :  CIVector(x:0,y:50), "inputPoint1": CIVector(x: 299,y:65),"inputColor0": CIColor(color: average1!),"inputColor1": CIColor(color: average2!)])
                
                maskCI = maskCI?.applyingFilter("CIExposureAdjust", parameters: ["inputEV": 0.04] )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CISmoothLinearGradient` doesn't need an input image (and hence doesn't have a property with that name). See [here](https://cifilter.io/CISmoothLinearGradient/). It's a generator, which means it will generate a new image (in this case a color gradient) from scratch.

The method `ciImage.applyingFilter("<name>", parameters: [<params>])` is a shortcut for the following:

```
let filter = CIFiter(name: "<name>")
filter.setValue(ciImage, forKey: "inputImage")
filter.setValuesForKeys([<params>])
return filter.outputImage
```

So this takes the image you are calling it on and sets it as the filter's `inputImage`, which doesn't work in this case.

You can generate a gradient image like this:

```
let gradientFilter = CIFilter(name: "CISmoothLinearGradient", parameters: [
    "inputPoint0":  CIVector(x:0,y:50),
    "inputPoint1": CIVector(x: 299,y:65),
    "inputColor0": CIColor(color: average1!),
    "inputColor1": CIColor(color: average2!)]))
let gradient = gradientFilter.outputImage
```

Or, if you support iOS 13 only and prefer a type-safe version:

```
import CoreImage.CIFilterBuiltins

let filter = CIFilter.smoothLinearGradient()
filter.color0 = CIColor(color: average1!)
filter.color1 = CIColor(color: average2!)
filter.point0 = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 50)
filter.point1 = CGPoint(x: 299, y: 65)
let gradient = filter.outputImage
```

Beware that the resulting image will have a (virtually) infinite extent (it's generated infinitely in all directions). This is usually what you want when you use it for blending later. But if you need it to be a certain size, you can just crop it to your needs:

```
let croppedGradient = gradient.cropped(to: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 500, height: 500)))
```

Comment: ok thank you. I had not realize it. But how can I use CISmoothLinearGradient to generate the  new image? I could not find any sample code showing how to use this filter. I am able to set the parameters but unable to generate the outputImage. 

Comment: great thanks. Second alternative worked fine as cropped. I am curious how to use a filter as infinite extent. When I tried to blend gradient with my CI image it crashed.  I guess below comment does not work for infinite CIimage                                        var trialImage = blendKernel.apply(foreground: maskCI!, background: gradientI!)

Comment: The output of that `blendKernel` will also have an infinite extent. You are basically placing an image (`maskCI`) on an infinite wallpaper (`gradient`). So you need to crop it at some point before you render the result because your rendering destination will be finite and you need to tell Core Image which part of your infinite image you want to display.

Comment: Ok I understand now. My mistake was to convert the result of blend kernel to UIimage and try to display it. Many thanks 